# .Net sorted sets - efficient range dissection operations

Tags: c#, data-structures

In an attempt to not reinvent the wheel, I've been looking for a fast, efficient data structure that I can use in my code which is somewhat analogous to Redis' sorted sets. 
Adding ranges of items is easy enough, but I've discovered that there doesn't seem to be anything that allows me to drop ranges of entries based on an upper and lower bound. For example, if my set is keyed on a `double`, I'd like to be able to drop all values between 0.3 and 0.7. I was quite surprised that I couldn't find any easy way to do this that felt like the correct approach. Also, performance is important for my use case, both in terms of speed and memory usage.

Examples and implementations from NuGet, CodeProject, GitHub, etc. are all acceptable.

p.s. For what it's worth, I'm wanting to maintain a cache of items indexed across 4 dimensions, and need to be able to discard items across different dimensional ranges when usage strays too far from a given range. Feel free to suggest something to this effect as well.